# form_for submit brings up Error 324.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form_for with a nested resource. Here are the nested routes to demonstrate my setup.

```
   resources :residents do
    resources :assessment_plan_forms
    resources :blood_pressure_record_forms
    resources :fund_record_form1s
    resources :fund_record_form2s
    resources :id_record_forms
    resources :incident_accident_forms
    resources :med_record_forms
    resources :personal_care_forms
    resources :resident_care_agreement_forms
    resources :visitation_appointment_forms
    resources :weight_record_forms
  end
```

I can navigate successfully from the resident/show view (which offers all the forms you see in the nested resources snippet) to the assessment_plan_form/new view with no problems.

However, when I click the submit button on the form I receive the following error.

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

When I click the reload hyperlink chrome provides, I am able to successfully redirect to the  assessment_plan_form/show view.

I'm hoping to receive insight into what went wrong as well as solutions to solve this issue.

I have included the following gist link for your consideration. If I need to provide more information let me know and I will make them available.

[Gist Link - includes code snippets, server log, and routes](https://gist.github.com/4366840)

Comment: I would like an explanation as to why my question was downvoted. Since  it wasn't obvious to the contributor, I will explain. I am unfortunately more likely to repeat the alleged offense out of naivety, due to the lack of receiving anything "constructive" in the anonymous criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure why this works, here is the solution I used to remove Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

First off, this issue occurred in both Firefox 17 & Chrome 23. I was able to quiet the error when I added the thin server to my Gemfile, ran bundle & restarted the server.

This removed the 324 error but currently I am unable to get the submit button to redirect to the show action. There are no exceptions generating, and the page only refreshes at all if I add a form validation in my model.

I will continue to troubleshoot and create a new question pertaining on the submit button not redirecting if need be.